# Postgres crosstab and aggregate together

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab, data-analysis

I have a table `purchases` like this:

```
purchase_id|purchase_date|product_id
     1     | 2016-02-04  | 17
     2     | 2016-02-04  | 19
     3     | 2016-02-04  | 17
     ... About 1 million entries
```

and a table `products` like this:

```
product_id
   17
   18
   19
   ... About 30 entries
```

I'd like to do a crosstab query to give me the total number of purchases on date, pivoted over each product_id, like this:

```
 purchase_date|product_id_17|product_id_18|product_id_19|product_id...
   2016-02-04 |   2         |  0          |  1          | ...
   2016-02-05 | ...
```

Note that the values in this table are *not* taken from any record, but **the sum of the number of records that match**.  I believe this is possible using `crosstab` along with aggregates, but haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

1. Can this be done using Postgres?
2. Is crosstab the right way to do it?
3. How?

What's unique here is that I am trying to:

- Do a crosstab
- Do an aggregate
- At the same time

Note that the other questions on Stack Overflow discussing Crosstab do not explain how to do a Crosstab and aggregate together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Edited to clarify the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With following as sample

Table-

```
 create table prods(purchase_id int,purchase_date date,product_id int);
```

Data-

```
 insert into prods values (1,'2016-02-04',17);
 insert into prods values (2,'2016-02-04',19);
 insert into prods values (3,'2016-02-04',17);
 insert into prods values (4,'2016-02-05',17);
 insert into prods values (5,'2016-02-05',17);
```

To get the desired output you can use [`crosstab()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tablefunc.html)-

```
select *
from crosstab('
 select purchase_date
       ,product_id
       ,count(product_id)::int
from    prods
group by purchase_date
        ,product_id
order by purchase_date
        ,product_id
') as t("purchase_date" date
        ,"product_id_17" int
        ,"product_id_19" int
        )
```

Output-

```
purchase_date product_id_17 product_id_19 
------------- ------------- ------------- 
2016-02-04    2             1             
2016-02-05    2             NULL
```